# Retrieving data of curl post in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I am trying to senddata to a url by using curl with codeigniter. I have successfully implemented the code for sending the data as below.

```
function postToURL($reg_no, $data)
{
    $url = 'http://localhost/abcSystem/Web_data/viewPage';

    $send_array = array(
        'reg_no' =>$reg_no,
        'data' =>$data,
    );

    $fields_string = http_build_query($send_array);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 600);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

    $post_data = 'json='.urlencode(json_encode($send_array));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        die('Couldn\'t send request: ' . curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($resultStatus == 200) {
            print_r('success'); // this is outputting
            return $output;
        } else {
            die('Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

The out put is **success**. I want to see if this post data can be retrieved. So I tried to change the above url controller file as below.

```
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$rawData = stream_get_contents($fp);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rawData);
echo "</pre>";
```

But nothing is printing. I want to get the data of posting. Please help me on this.

Comment: Don't `return $output`. Instead `echo` it. It needs to be accessible in the DOM/Content.

Comment: @Darren still no output showing.

Answer (score 1):

Your Written code

```
$fp = fopen('php://input', 'r');
$rawData = stream_get_contents($fp);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rawData);
echo "</pre>";
```

is not to Print or capture Posted Data . Because you are dealing with Current Page PHP INPUT Streaming  , whereas you are posting data on Other URL . So what you need to do is just Put a log of posted data in File. Use below code after $output = curl_exec($ch)

```
file_put_contents("posted_data.txt", $post_data );
```

This way you will be able to write your each post in file Posted_data.txt File - Make sure you give proper File Permission. If you want to keep trace of each POST than just make the file name dynamic so per API Call it can write a log.

Another option is to save the $post_data in DATABASE - Which is not suggestable from Security point of view.

Comment: I tested it out. txt file is creating with data. How can I show that data in the given url's system?.

Comment: To show Posted Data in the given url's system - you need to write logic over that url's code. That depends on your business logic how to handle and display it. However Curl is Not Something to be used for that purpose. you should opt for Iframe for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you are calling your `postToURL()` function, you need to output the result of it.

For example:

```
$output = postToURL('Example', array());
echo $output;
```

This is because you are **returning** the curl output rather outputting it.

Comment: I am calling it and passing data. that is not hte problem. I want to test out if this posting  data to the given url.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand your question.

Comment: The question is how can I confirm and print out that posted data in the side of the url(receiver).